# Функция MAP вывод на экран

Tags: java

Приветсвую всех, cитуация такая, есть ArrayList, в него добавляем 5 кораблей (грузовой, пассажирский(2), военный(2))

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
                    for (Ships s: newFleetShips.getShips()) {
                        if(result.containsKey(s.getShips())) {
                            result.put(s.getShips(),result.get(s.getShips())+1);

                        } else {
                            result.put(s.getShips(),1);
                        }
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
```

Вывод в консоль такой:

```
{Грузовой=1}
{Пассажирский=1, Грузовой=1}
{Пассажирский=2, Грузовой=1}
{Пассажирский=2, Военный=1, Грузовой=1}
{Пассажирский=2, Военный=2, Грузовой=1}
```

Не могу понять почему так

Хочу получить такой вывод:
Грузовой - 1
Пассажирский - 2
Военный - 2

Comment: поместите `System.out.println(result);`  за цикл

Comment: а так же "HashMap и Hashtable не гарантируют, что элементы будут храниться в порядке добавления. "

Comment: @СергейМишин, спасибо, а я голову ломаю, что я делаю не так)

Comment: и если порядок добавления нужно соблюдать  - используйте TreeMap

Comment: @СергейМишин, а можно сделать такой вывод, не прибегая к Map?